# currency symbol disable in home or internal page of product

Tags: product, php, admin, price, code

I have this online store based on magento,
now, either in home page or product page, you could note that there is no any symbole of currency beside the price, just price without its currency symbol.
what should I do to show the symbol of currency beside every price in all my online store pages ?

Answer (score 0):

For Getting Price symbol in Try this

```
<?php echo Mage::app()->getLocale()->currency(Mage::app()->getStore()->getCurrentCurrencyCo‌​de())->getSymbol(); ?>
```

Comment: from where should I found that code, and what is happen when i found this code, I mean, what should I add or delete ?

Comment: You want to display currency symbol then you add this code in you price.html